# Python inserting data to multiprocessing pools

Tags: python

I am trying to make faster some calculations by parallelizing the work, but I don´t know how to insert data to my function.

```
def calculate(a, b, c):
    print(a * b + c)
```

I need somehow to insert to `pool.map()` command b and c along with a (for each value in list a).
I can create come frankenstain like this: `[[1, b, c], [2, b, c], ...]` and properly change my function, but it is unnecessary computation and I think there is better way to insert those variable.

```
a_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = 10
c = 20
async with Pool() as pool:
    await pool.map(command, a_list # and somehow b and c)
```

**Note: a, b and c are not static in my program so I need to insert all three things and computation is much more complex and slow than this.**

Comment: I usually make a tuple, which I unpack in the def.
`
async with Pool() as pool:
    await pool.map(command, [(a_list[jt], b[jt], c[jt]) for jt in range(nt)])
`

Comment: @Giovanni does it work with aiomultiprocess too?

Comment: doesen´t work:

`data = [(ctx, program[i], path) for i in range(len(program))]

print(data)

async with Pool() as pool:

 await pool.map(command, data)`

works:

`data = [(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9)]

print(data)

async with Pool() as pool:

 await pool.map(command, data)`

ctx is from discord, program is string and path is also string

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python39_64\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 245, in _feed
    obj = _ForkingPickler.dumps(obj)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python39_64\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: cannot pickle '_asyncio.Future' object`

this is error message when `program` is 1 long
if its n long then copy error message n times behind it self